# Accessibility of inner class members from enclosing class

Tags: java, iterator, inner-classes, access-modifiers

I thought members of an inner class, even when declared private, is accessible from its enclosing class. But I am running into compile time error with the following code structure. My top level class implements Iterable interface. The Iterator is implemented in an inner class. When an instance of the inner class is obtained through the iterator() method, I am not able to access the data field with that instance.

```
public class RandomQueue<Item> implements Iteralbe<Item>
{
     public RandomQueue() {}            
     public Iterator<Item> iterator()        // iterator() method
     { 
         return new ShuffleIterator();
     }
     // inner class implementing iterator
     private class ShuffleIterator implements Iterator<Item>  
     {
         private int i;      // private data field in inner class.
         .......
         public boolean hasNext()  {...}
         public Item next()   {...}
         public void remove()  {...} 
     }

     public void doSomething()
     {
         // Compile time error. "i cannot be resolved or is not a field"
         int j = iterator().i;     
     }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The type `Iterator` does not have an accessible field named `i`. What do you think you're accessing with `iterator().i`?

Comment: I am hoping to implement the Iterator so it iterates through an array and shuffle it while doing so. Therefore I added in some data fields and methods apart from the interface abstract methods. iterator().someDataField needs to return the results of shuffling operation.

Comment: To be clear: this is not about inner classes, nor is it about `private`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the return type of your method `iterator()` is `Iterator<Item>`, and you don't have any variable `i` in the class `Iterator<Item>`.

If your method was:

```
 public ShuffleIterator iterator()        // iterator() method
     { 
         return new ShuffleIterator();
     }
```

Then you will not have any compile error as `i` exist in the `ShuffleIterator` class.

Comment: For some reason I get an error (with no more details) if I try to upvote this (reproduced x3), but not if I try to upvote the other answer.

Comment: Just returning `ShuffleIterator` doesn't seem like a good idea though because then you are exposing the private member class.

Comment: @immibis really? i don't know why but no issue :)

Comment: @Radiodef Yes you are right, but I wanted to update to use casting, then i saw Sotirios Delimanolis's answer which include casting, so if i add it to my answer then it will be just a copy :)

Comment: @Radiodef: could you elaborate why returning ShuffleIterator exposes private member class?

Comment: @Tarik everyone gets an instance of ShuffleIterator anyway.

Comment: @Muye It shouldn't cause a problem, it's just a sloppy style.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `iterator`

```
 public Iterator<Item> iterator()        // iterator() method
```

is declared to return a value of type `Iterator<Item>`.

The type `Iterator` does not have an accessible field named `i`.

Your `ShuffleIterator` does. Either cast the returned value or change the return type.